# Error in SQL syntax Check Manual Correspond to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

*I'm getting this error*:

> Error Number: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from uhd_product where product_name and product_code like '%654321%'' at line 1

*MySQL Query look like*:

```
SELECT from uhd_product where product_name and product_code like '%654321%'
```

*PHP Function*:

```
function search($cari)
{
    $cari=$this->db->query("SELECT from uhd_product where product_name and product_code like '%$cari%' ");
    return $cari->result();;
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? I am doing a search with 2 record value in my database.

Comment: You need to specify a column name, ie. `SELECT id FROM uhd_product ...` or use `*`, ie. `SELECT * FROM uhd_product ...`, as `SELECT from` is invalid syntax

Comment: Also, `... where product_name and product_code like '%$cari%' ` is also invalid, as it should be something like `WHERE product_name LIKE '%$cari%' OR product_code LIKE '%$cari%' `.

Comment: Also, you are using `$cari` in your query `'%$cari%' `, which is a function property -> `function search($cari)`. So why are you overwriting it -> `$cari=$this->db->query(...)`??

Comment: thank you it has worked!

Comment: im using '%$cari%' from my controller its for search function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM uhd_product 
      where product_name like '%$cari%' 
      OR product_code LIKE '%$cari%'
```